# Android Wifi-direct groups and services

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have two Android devices I would like to connect to each other via wifi-direct.

One of them is display only (device A) and therefore has no input devices like touchscreens or mouse. The other would be a mobile phone (device B). Therefore I would like device A to be the device to initiate the connection to device B, so that the pop-up accept dialog would be displayed on device B.
I've done some research and testing on wifi-direct groups, and have managed to connect the two devices together. Unfortunately, as device A is display only, I would like to give device A some level of smarts so that it only connects to wifi-direct groups that are running a compatible app. I'm trying to do this via wifi-direct local services.

The plan is for device B to broadcast a service, and device A to listen to that service. Once device A finds the service, it will connect to device B. Then, device A would advertise its own service, so that device B, the mobile phone, will know that it can proceed with the application communication.

So far, I've noticed that you're able to see a service before the wifi-direct group is created. I would like to ask some questions about how the wifi-direct should work:

- If one device sees a service, but not connected to a group that contains the device that's broadcasting the service, then I assume you cannot connect to the service/device directly? It's always i) connect to group, then ii) connect to the device.
- If so, since I can see a service without being in the same group as the service broadcaster, then how would I know that the device broadcasting the service is in my device's current wifi-direct group, and that I'm connecting to the same device? 
  I know that you can get a "peers list" of currently connected peers in a group, but is there a good way to make the association that "service broadcaster" == "this specific peer?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are on the right track.

Regarding the first question: A device can connect to any peer thats advertising a local service. Even if they are not in the same group, when a device connects to another one, they form another / new group automatically, see the next question answer explaining how to get the service peer.

For the second question: it's possible to associate discovered services with specific peers, without even calling get peers list. You can follow this way:

Implement the local service listeners before initiating service discovery:

```
WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener dnsListener = new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName, String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice device) { 
           // instanceName is service name and device is the print information
}};


WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener txtListener = new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(String fullDomain, Map record, WifiP2pDevice device) {
            // here we get the service published information in the record map object
}};
```

Notice that each of them returns a `WifiP2pDevice device` object, you can use this object to connect to the device using the manager connect method and cache the list of services mapping them to their devices.

Hope this helps, goodluck.

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive answer. I would like to ask for more clarification about this point though, 
"A device can connect to any peer thats advertising a local service. Even if they are not in the same group, when a device connects to another one, they form another / new group automatically"
Do I need to ensure that a device connecting to a group connects to the current group leader? Or can it just connect to a peer and it'll all sort itself out?

Comment: Good point, yes, you have to ensure connecting to the group owner, otherwise you will establish a new group. Usually, after establishing a group, all devices turn off service advertising so that the group owner is the only service available. Or better solution is that all devices turn off service advertising and server starts a new service with different name that can be used to understand that there is a service already established and this device is the owner.